# Do login command with AppleScript

Tags: bash, applescript

Prettty straightforward–Is there a way to do the login command and then enter the login password with *do shell script?*

For example, I want to login into the account **user** with the password **name**. How can I get the script to do *login user* and then input the password *name* (without opening a new Terminal window)? Maybe some bash script executable with

```
do shell script "./mybashscript.sh"
```

That does the login and inputs the password. I want it to do this **invisibly**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're referring to **automating logging in as a different OSX user**, as opposed to running a shell command as another user: **I wouldn't know how to do that**.

If you're referring to **running shell commands or a shell script as another user**, that's doable, although it **requires administrative credentials** - NOT the *target* user's password, but the password of a user with administrative privileges.

The following solutions simply execute `whoami` in the context of the target user, which echoes that user's username.

- The **SECURE way**: ***prompt* for administrative credentials**:

```applescript
set targetUser to "user1"
do shell script "sudo -H -s -u " & targetUser & " whoami" with administrator privileges
```

- The **INSECURE way**: ***hard-code* the administrative credentials**:

```applescript
set targetUser to "user1"
set adminUser to "admin"
set adminPasswd to "adminPassword" # !! NOT RECOMMENDED
do shell script "sudo -H -s -u " & targetUser & " whoami" ¬
  user name adminUser password adminPasswd with administrator privileges
```

Omit the `user name adminUser` clause if you want to default to the current user, assuming it is an administrator.

As for the options passed to `sudo`:

- `-s` causes the command (`whoami`, in this case) to be executed by a (non-login) *shell* (an instance of the *current* user's shell).
- `-H` ensures that the `$HOME` environment variable is set to the target user's, which ensures that the *target* user's shell initialization files are read.

Comment: I originally wanted it to do the login command, but this works just as well. Thanks.